# Let $ M $ be a maximal subgroup of a solvable group $ G $, and assume that $ G=MC $, for some cyclic subgroup $ C $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $ M $ be a maximal subgroup of a solvable group $ G $, and assume that $ G=MC $, for some cyclic subgroup $ C $. Then $ \vert G : M \vert $ is a prime or $ 4 $. Also if $ \vert G : M \vert = 4 $ , then $ G/M_{G} = S_{4} $.

Proof: If let $ M_{G} \neq 1 $, how proof this case by induction on $ G/M_{G} $?

If $ M_{G}= 1 $, Let $ N $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Then $ N $ is an
elementary abelian $ p $-group and $ M $ is a complement for $ N $ in $ G $. $ M \cap C \leq M $, so $ M \cap C = 1 $ since $ M_{G} = 1 $.Thus $ \vert C \vert = \vert G : M \vert = \vert N \vert $ is a power of $ p $. Let $ P = NC $, so $ P $ is $ p $-group and let $ S = P \cap M $, so $ S $ complements $ N $ in $ P $. Also $ P = CS $ by Dedekind modular law.  Then $ N $ is a prime or $ 4 $ and thus $ \vert G : M \vert $ is a prime or $ 4 $.

Comment: Can you provide some reference for your proposition in the first paragraph, and what is $M_G$?

Comment: Theorem 1.3 of http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219498812502179 article. $ M_{G} $ is core of  $ M $ in $ G $.

Comment: Presumably the proof is by induction on $|G|$. So if $M_G \ne 1$ then $|G/M_G|<|G|$, so the theorem is true in $G/M_G$. So $|G/M_G:M/M_G|$ is prime or $4$. But $|G/M_G:M/M_G| = |G:M|$ so $|G:M|$ is prime or $4$ and the theorem is true in $G$. (This is the easiest part of the proof!)