# $ G = MC $ for some cyclic subgroup $ C $. If $ \vert G : M \vert = 4 $ then why $ G \cong S_{4} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $ M $ is a maximal subgroup of finite group $ G $, that $ G = MC $ for some cyclic subgroup $ C $. If $ \vert G : M \vert = 4 $ and $ M_{G} = 1 $ then why $ G\cong S_{4} $?

Comment: $ G/M_{G} $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $ S_{4} $.

Comment: It is a primitive subgroup of $S_4$, so it must be $A_4$ or $S_4$. But if $G/M_G = A_4$ then $|M/M_G|=3$ and there is no cyclic subgroup $C$ with $G=MC$. So it must be $S_4$.

Comment: You shoul link to [the earlier version](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1398387/11619). Leaving it to the others to decide whether this is a duplicate. A site rule (strictly upheld) is not to reask the same question.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why there is no cyclic subgroup $ C $ with $ G = MC $ ?

Comment: Elements of $A_4$ have orders $1,2$ or $3$, so there is no cyclic group of order $4$ or more.